# "attempt to index number with 'transparency'" How do I fix this?

Tags: lua, game-development, roblox

function changeTransparency(changePart, newTransparency)
changePart.transparency = newTransparency
end

changeTransparency(game.workspace.functionPart.Transparency, 1)

wait(2)

changeTransparency(game.Workspace.functionPart.Transparency, 0.25)

Comment: Please use code tag.

Answer (score 1):

The function is trying to access functionPart.Transparency.transparency, and since functionPart.Transparency is a number, it gives the error.

Try changing the function to this, and passing in the part as an argument instead of the part's transparency.

```lua
function changeTransparency(changePart, newTransparency) 
    changePart.Transparency = newTransparency
end

changeTransparency(game.Workspace.functionPart, 1)

task.wait(2) -- more accurate than wait(2)

changeTransparency(game.Workspace.functionPart, 0.25)
```

Also make sure case is correct, Part.Transparency and Part.transparency are different.